# Unable to fetch all data from 2 tables using leftjoin

Tags: mysql, nestjs, typeorm

Iam unable to fetch all columns from the query, I got the result only 1 table, and Im expecting other table also, Here I have 2 tables a) registration_types and b)packages. I got the result of registration_types but I did not get the packages table

```
   return await createQueryBuilder("registration_types")
            .leftJoinAndSelect("packages", "pk", "pk.registration_type_id = registration_types.id")
            .getMany();
```

I got the results, but not all the colums

Answer (score 0):

Hey you should try the following query:

```
return await createQueryBuilder("registration_types")
    .leftJoinAndSelect("registration_types.packages", Package, "pk", "pk.registration_type_id = registration_types.id")
    .getMany();
```

OR

```
return await createQueryBuilder("registration_types")
    .leftJoinAndMapMany("registration_types.packages", Package, "pk", "pk.registration_type_id = registration_types.id")
    .getMany();
```

Comment: for the first solution Iam getting error, and for 2 solutions I got the results but ,in this I got only registration_types result , not the packages result.I have done in other way like raw query ,

Comment: `return await getConnection().query(
            SELECT regType.start_date, regType.end_date, regType.type_name as package, pkg.package_name as packageName, pkg.price, pkg.total_seats
            FROM packages as pkg
             left join registration_types as regType on regType.id = pkg.registration_type_id 
    );`

Comment: above is what I got the result , but I don't want write like that, is another solutions

Comment: Can you tell me what is the query that have been builded by the orm by logging it please

Comment: by writting QueryRunner from 'typeorm';

Comment: But the generated query ^^

Comment: That will help to find why there is not the expected result

Answer (score 0):

Hey you should try the following query:

```
return await getManager().createQueryBuilder(registrationTypesEntity, "registration_types")
    .leftJoinAndSelect("registration_types.packages", PackageEntity, "pk", "pk.registration_type_id = registration_types.id")
    .getMany();
```

OR:

```
return await getManager().createQueryBuilder(registrationTypesEntity, "registration_types")
    .leftJoinAndSelect("registration_types.packages")
    .getMany();
```